# What is the cause of a "No network connection" banner?

Tags: networking, google-pixel

This banner randomly appears, persists across mobile and WiFi networks, and then randomly disappears, and I don't know where to begin to search for the issue.

[image: No network connection banner]

Comment: I'm seeing the same banner on my OnePlus 5. But it's on the bottom for me.

Comment: What browser?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the bar is [gray and at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgtCe.png). The bar is drawn over all other apps and is always visible.

To check which apps have this capability:

1. Open the **Settings**.
2. Navigate to **Apps** (under the *Personal* section).
3. Open the configuration by tapping on the cogwheel icon in the top right.
4. Open **Special access** (under the *Advanced* section).
5. Open **Draw over other apps**.

This already made it much more apparent which apps are candidates for this issue. The next time the issue appeared, I closed apps one by one until the bar disappeared.

In *my* case, the app causing the bar was **Office 365 Admin**.

Comment: I do have that app installed on my device, I'll check that next time it comes up, thanks for the tip!